# Proper use of try/catch in SSIS C# Script Component to skip failed DB inserts

Tags: c#, ssis, ssis-2012

Just starting to get up to speed with SSIS error handling. We are using a Script Component as a final step in our Data Flow.  In the Input0_ProcessInputRow method, I am assigning values to the parameters of a stored procedure.  Some of the data being passed fails validation (referential integrity, etc.) and cannot be inserted.  Long term, I wish to log those failures so we can review them later.  Right now, the issue is, once we hit one of these records, the entire SSIS step fails.  No records get added.

I wrapped the code in a try/catch expecting the failing records to just be skipped and move on to the next one.

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    try
    {
        sqlCmd.Parameters["@FIRSTNAME"].Value = Row.DRIVERFIRSTNAME;
        sqlCmd.Parameters["@LASTNAME"].Value = Row.DRIVERLASTNAME;
        sqlCmd.Parameters["@STATUS"].Value = "Active";
        sqlCmd.Parameters["@SHOPID"].Value = Row.DRIVERSHOPID;
        sqlCmd.Parameters["@ADDRESS1"].Value = Row.DRIVERADDRESS1;
        sqlCmd.Parameters["@ADDRESS2"].Value = Row.DRIVERADDRESS2;
        sqlCmd.Parameters["@CITY"].Value = Row.DRIVERCITY;
        sqlCmd.Parameters["@STATE"].Value = Row.DRIVERSTATE;
        sqlCmd.Parameters["@ZIPCODE"].Value = Row.DRIVERZIPCODE;

        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //bool pbCancel = false;
        //this.ComponentMetaData.FireError(0, "SQL Task", "An error occurred: " + ex.Message, "", 0, out pbCancel);
    }
}
```

Many of the examples I find are for VB and are pretty old.  So far, none that I try have worked.

How do I skip the failing records and allow the others to proceed?

Comment: What of this would cause your row to fail? You might want to consider checking that in a conditional split in the data flow. That way you can move "bad" records into it's own output (or actually do something to fix them)..

Answer (score 0):

This will work. Try this:

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace RestSharpClient
{
class RestClientDB
{
    public static void AddJSONInfo(ChildGetSet jResult)
    {
        bool debugging = false;


        SqlConnection connection = Connection.GetConnection();

        connection.Open();

        try
        {

            ///Check to see if the orderID already exists in the database

            string check = @"(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM OrdersSubTable WHERE FOrderID='" + jResult.FOrderID + "' AND OrderItemID='" +
                jResult.OrderItemID + "')";
            SqlCommand cmda = new SqlCommand(check, connection);
            int count = (int)cmda.ExecuteScalar();

            if (debugging == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("count: " + count);
            }
            if (count > 0)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("Order number: " + Convert.ToString(jResult.FOrderID) + " already exists with Item Number: " + jResult.OrderItemID + ".");

                SqlCommand update = new SqlCommand("UPDATE OrdersSubTable SET FOrderStatus=@FOrderStatus, OrderItemID=@OrderItemID, " +
                    "ItemState=@ItemState, PartNumber=@PartNumber, Warehouse=@Warehouse, Description=@Description, Quantity=@Quantity, " +
                    "SubtotalTaxAmount=@SubtotalTaxAmount, SubtotalGross=@SubtotalGross, RetailPrice=@RetailPrice, MfgOfferPrice=@MfgOfferPrice, " +
                    "LineDiscount=@LineDiscount, Shipping=@Shipping, ActualPrice=@ActualPrice, Code=@Code, SingleUseCode=@SingleUseCode, " +
                    "Amount=@Amount, IsInventory=@IsInventory, IsGift=@IsGift, IsExternalPayment=@IsExternalPayment " +
                    "Where FOrderID=" + jResult.FOrderID + " AND OrderItemID=" +
                jResult.OrderItemID, connection);
                update.Parameters.AddWithValue(
                    "@FOrderStatus", jResult.FOrderStatus);
                update.Parameters.AddWithValue(
                    "@OrderItemID", jResult.OrderItemID);

                update.Parameters.AddWithValue(
                    "@ItemState", jResult.ItemState);
                update.Parameters.AddWithValue(
                    "@PartNumber", jResult.PartNumber);
                update.Parameters.AddWithValue(
                    "@Warehouse", jResult.Warehouse);
                update.Parameters.AddWithValue(
                    "@Description", jResult.Description);
                update.Parameters.AddWithValue(
                    "@Quantity", jResult.Quantity);
                update.Parameters.AddWithValue(
                    "@SubtotalTaxAmount", jResult.SubtotalTaxAmount);
                update.Parameters.AddWithValue(
                    "@SubtotalGross", jResult.SubtotalGross);
                update.Parameters.AddWithValue(
                    "@RetailPrice", jResult.RetailPrice);
                update.Parameters.AddWithValue(
                    "@MfgOfferPrice", jResult.MfgOfferPrice);
                update.Parameters.AddWithValue(
                    "@LineDiscount", jResult.LineDiscount);
                update.Parameters.AddWithValue(
                    "@Shipping", jResult.Shipping);
                update.Parameters.AddWithValue(
                    "@ActualPrice", jResult.ActualPrice);
                update.Parameters.AddWithValue(
                        "@Code", jResult.Code);
                update.Parameters.AddWithValue(
                        "@SingleUseCode", jResult.SingleUseCode);
                update.Parameters.AddWithValue(
                        "@Amount", jResult.Amount);
                update.Parameters.AddWithValue(
                        "@IsInventory", jResult.IsInventory);
                update.Parameters.AddWithValue(
                        "@IsGift", jResult.IsGift);
                update.Parameters.AddWithValue(
                        "@IsExternalPayment", jResult.IsExternalPayment);
                update.ExecuteNonQuery();

                if (debugging == true)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("If " + jResult.FOrderStatus + " is different, then it would have changed.");
                }
            }
            else
            {




                string insertStatement2 =
                    "INSERT INTO OrdersSubTable " +
                    "(FOrderID, FOrderStatus, OrderItemID, " +
                    "ItemState, PartNumber, Warehouse, Description, Quantity, SubtotalTaxAmount, " +
                    "SubtotalGross, RetailPrice, MfgOfferPrice, LineDiscount, Shipping, ActualPrice, Code, SingleUseCode, Amount, " +
                    "IsInventory, IsGift, IsExternalPayment) " + "VALUES (@FOrderID, @FOrderStatus, " +
                    "@OrderItemID, " +
                    "@ItemState, @PartNumber, @Warehouse, @Description, @Quantity, @SubtotalTaxAmount, " +
                    "@SubtotalGross, @RetailPrice, @MfgOfferPrice, @LineDiscount, @Shipping, @ActualPrice, @Code, @SingleUseCode, " +
                    "@Amount, @IsInventory, @IsGift, @IsExternalPayment)";



                SqlCommand insertCommand2 =
                   new SqlCommand(insertStatement2, connection);
                insertCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue(
                    "@FOrderID", jResult.FOrderID);
                insertCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue(
                    "@FOrderStatus", jResult.FOrderStatus);
                insertCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue(
                    "@OrderItemID", jResult.OrderItemID);
                insertCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue(
                    "@ItemState", jResult.ItemState);
                insertCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue(
                    "@PartNumber", jResult.PartNumber);
                insertCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue(
                    "@Warehouse", jResult.Warehouse);
                insertCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue(
                    "@Description", jResult.Description);
                insertCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue(
                    "@Quantity", jResult.Quantity);
                insertCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue(
                    "@SubtotalTaxAmount", jResult.SubtotalTaxAmount);
                insertCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue(
                    "@SubtotalGross", jResult.SubtotalGross);
                insertCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue(
                    "@RetailPrice", jResult.RetailPrice);
                insertCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue(
                    "@MfgOfferPrice", jResult.MfgOfferPrice);
                insertCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue(
                    "@LineDiscount", jResult.LineDiscount);
                insertCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue(
                    "@Shipping", jResult.Shipping);
                insertCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue(
                    "@ActualPrice", jResult.ActualPrice);
                insertCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue(
                        "@Code", jResult.Code);
                insertCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue(
                        "@SingleUseCode", jResult.SingleUseCode);
                insertCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue(
                        "@Amount", jResult.Amount);
                insertCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue(
                        "@IsInventory", jResult.IsInventory);
                insertCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue(
                        "@IsGift", jResult.IsGift);
                insertCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue(
                        "@IsExternalPayment", jResult.IsExternalPayment);


                insertCommand2.ExecuteNonQuery();

                //MessageBox.Show("Data Successfully written to database.");
            }

        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            if (ex.Number == 2627)
            {
                if (debugging == true)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Violation of primary/unique key. Exception number: " + ex);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (debugging == true)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("SQL Exception number: " + ex);
                }
            }
        }
        connection.Close();


    }
}
}
```

Of course you are going to have to pass your own connection, variable names, parameters, etc, but this is a good read.

Comment: I might even add the if statement that says if (connection != null) { connection.Close() }